# Excel data to json using node

Tags: node.js, converters

Here i have upload my excel file, now i need to convert it to json,but it's  showing the following error:

```
   TypeError: Cannot set property length of [object Object] which has only a getter
```

Here is my code:

```
//other module dependencies also given
var converter = require('xls-to-json')
var Data      = {};

exports.fnup = function(req, res) {

    var upfile = req.file;
    var userid = req.body.userid || '0';
    if (uploafile.fieldname !== 'myFile') {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: 'Please upload '
        });
    }

    converter({
        input: './foldern1/' + upfile.originalname,
        output: null
    }, 
    function(err, results) {
        console.log("hheeelo");
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error:', err);
        } else {
            console.log("suvbb", results);
            Data = _.filter(results, function(result) {});
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Which is the line you're getting that error at?

Comment: after converter, results itself not printing in console.log.showing a above error.

Comment: C:\Users\User\Music>node mj.js
C:\Users\User\Music\node_modules\xls-to-json\node_modules\xlsjs\dist\cpexcel.js:
904
        mdb.length = 2 * len;
                   ^

TypeError: Cannot set property length of [object Object] which has only a getter

    at sbcs_d (C:\Users\User\Music\node_modules\xls-to-json\node_modules\xlsjs\d
ist\cpexcel.js:904:20)
    at Object.decode (C:\Users\User\Music\node_modules\xls-to-json\node_modules\
xlsjs\dist\cpexcel.js:1187:40)
    at _gc2 (C:\Users\User\Music\node_modules\xls-to-json\node_modules\xlsjs\xls
.js:19:23)

Comment: showing error not in my code,it seems to be error in  cpexcel.js in xsl-json module

Answer (score 0):

`_.filter` only works with an `Array`, not an `Object`. `results` is an `Object`.